# Is there anyway to use variable in search function of Regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I wonder if there is any way to use a special variable in regex and mix it with regex code??
this is a function that takes type and folder and searches all files and folders in it to find all files with that type. and the error occurred in line 10 when I tried to combine them.

```
def explore(extension,path):
    import os
    import re
    d = dict()
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        count = 0
        for filename in files:
            fname = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
            fname = fname.lower()
            j = ".\"+extension+"$"
            if re.search(j,fname) != None:
                if fname.endswith(extension):
                    count+=1
                    d[dirpath]=count
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error here is missing one ". When you do ", then it means that quote sign is just a character. It doesn't end your string. To get rid of this error, you can do it in two ways:

First - use r before string. It treats characters in string as regular characters:

```
        j = r".\"+extension+"$"
```

Second - use double slash. Double slash will result in one, regular character slash.

```
j = ".\\"+extension+"$"
```

As an addition. It's better to use for example fstrings rather than concatenating strings. Try syntax below :)

```
print(f"Hello. My name is {your_variable}!")
```